# How to Add to an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollections with different types

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to add to an `ObservableCollection` of `ObservableCollections` of different types. The types come from a base class, in this example I use 'Animal'. When trying to add to the `Observable Collection`, like in the code below, I get the following error:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Cat>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Animal>'
```

.

```
public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Animal>> Animals { get; set; }
private ObservableCollection<Dog> Dogs = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();
private ObservableCollection<Cat> Cats = new ObservableCollection<Cat>();
private ObservableCollection<Bird> Birds = new ObservableCollection<Bird>();

public DefaultConstructor()
{
    Animals = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Animal>>()
    { Cats, Dogs, Birds };
}
```

Example of classes:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    ...
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
    ...
}
public class Cat : Animal
{
    ...
}
public class Bird : Animal
{
    ...
}
```

I have also tried making the `ObservableCollection` simply take the type of `ObservableCollection<object>`, but the result was the same.

Comment: You would need to use an interface, rather than an abstract class

Comment: @Jaxi Shouldn't making it ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>> allow it to accept any object irregardless of this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the single observable collection for the base class and the filter methods:

```
public class AnimalContainer : ObservableCollection<Animal>
{
    public IEnumerable<Dog> Dogs => this.Where(animal => animal is Dog).Cast<Dog>();
    public IEnumerable<Cat> Cats => this.Where(animal => animal is Cat).Cast<Cat>();
}

//...
AnimalContainer container = new AnimalContainer();

container.Add(new Dog());
container.Add(new Cat());

int dogsCount = container.Dogs.Count();
int catsCount = container.Cats.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use interface? Say you have an interface for Animal classes.

```
    public interface IAnimal{
}
```

Dog and Cat will implement the `IAnimal` interface like under:

```
public class Dog: IAnimal{
}
public class Cat:IAnimal{
}
```

Now, say you want to have a collection that will contain both Cats and Dogs. Just do:

```
ObservableCollection<IAnimal> animals=new  ObservableCollection (){
new Dog (),
new Cat()
};
```

Almost the same logic applies to an `abstract` class.
Consider a simple Animal abstract class.

```
public abstract class Animal
    {
        public abstract string GetName(string animalName);
        //I dont know what to do!
    }
```

**DOG CLASS**

```
public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override string GetName(string animalName)
        {
            return animalName;
        }
    }
```

**CUTE CAT CLASS**

```
public class Cat : Animal {
        public override string GetName(string animalName)
        {
            return animalName;
        }
    }
```

**A LIST OF DOGS AND CATS**

```
public class DoStuff{
        public void TestThings()
        {
            List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>()
        {
            new Dog(),
            new Cat()
        };
            foreach(Animal animal in animals)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(animal.GetName("My name is: "+animal.GetType()));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

```
My name is: StuffClass.Dog
My name is: StuffClass.Cat
```

Comment: Good answer, but I should have specified in the OP that this is part of a larger project where I need to use an abstract class instead of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Animal as an interface you could do the following:

```
public interface Animal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bird : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then in the class with Animals:

```
private List<Dog> Dogs = new List<Dog>();
private List<Cat> Cats = new List<Cat>();
private List<Bird> Birds = new List<Bird>();

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    Animals = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Animal>>();
    Animals.Add(new ObservableCollection<Animal>(Cats));
    Animals.Add(new ObservableCollection<Animal>(Dogs));
    Animals.Add(new ObservableCollection<Animal>(Birds));
}

public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Animal>> Animals { get; set; }
```

This will get your Property populated with the collections required.
In you code you could then create helper methods as such:

```
private void AddToCats()
{
    ObservableCollection<Animal> cats = Animals.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Any(cat => cat is Cat));
    cats.Add(new Cat{Name = "Biggles"});
}
```

This is guessing that you'd want to work on the individual ObservableCollection's after the initial population.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are doing what your task requires you to do such as the observable collections and abstract class (which you did point out you must do).  I recreated your classes but in my implementation here is how I did the implementation without getting build errors.

```
public class BuildZoo
{
  private ObservableCollection<Animal> cats = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
  private ObservableCollection<Animal> dogs = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
  private ObservableCollection<Animal> birds = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();

  private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Animal>> zoo =
  new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Animal>>();

  public void construct ()
  { zoo. Add(cats);
    zoo.Add(dogs);
    zoo.Add(birds);
    cats.Add(new Cat());
    dogs.Add(new Dog());
    birds.Add(new Bird());
  }
}
```

If you need to have a strong-type validation that a dog is getting added to the dog collection, you would have to do your own collection that inherits ObservableColletion and override the Add logic.

```
  public class DogCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
  {
    public new void Add(T animal)
    {
      if (animal is Dog)
        base.Add(animal);
      throw new InvalidCastException("Animal is not a Dog");
    }
  }
```

So with ObservableCollection you would replace each animal collection with DogCollection, CatCollection,...  The rest of the base class would do it's thing.